# A more efficient way of commenting out the two functions in vim

Tags: vim, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

I have two functions in java, I'll make them up for now:

```
public void functionOne() {
    //
}

public void functionTwo() {
   //
}
```

In Vim I wanted to comment them out, I used line number followed by GG to go the top of the first function, insert mode and /* then I used the line number followed by GG to go to the end of the second function shif+A to go the end in insert mode end */ to close the comment, is there a more efficient or easier way of doing this or is that already pretty quick, I felt it was really long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For commenting I strongly recommend using a plugin. Many different plugins are available and very easy to find.

With [***commentary.vim***](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3695) this task is a piece of cake:

1. `42G` to move to the top of the first function,
2. `gc2ap` to comment out two paragraphs.

`gc` is the new commenting operator provided by *commentary.vim*, `ap` is the text object "a paragraph", and `2` is the count: two paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you, it is an easier way :)

Comment: You can use `[m` and `%` to make jumping around methods easier. See `:h [m` and `:h %` for more information.